# Infix to Profix conversion using linked list problems

Tags: c, algorithm

I am a beginner in coding and have been trying to fix this code for like three hours now, which should be way too much for how simple it is. It prints nothing as soon as I give it an operator. If there is no operator inputted then it just prints out whatever I inputted. I cannot figure out what is wrong for the life of me. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *top = NULL;               

void push(char x){
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = top;
    top = temp;
}

char pop(){
    struct node *temp = top;
    char op;

    if(top == NULL){
        printf("Stack Empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    op = top -> data;
    temp = top;
    top = temp -> next;
    free(temp);
    return op;
}

int precedence(char x){
    switch (x){
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isOperand(char x){
    if(x=='^' || x=='/' || x=='+' || x=='-' || x=='*') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){
    char x[100];
    char c[100];
    printf("Enter infix expression: \n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    
    int i = 0;
    int j =0;

    while(c[i]){
        if(isOperand){
           if ((precedence(c[i])) >= (precedence(top->data)) || top == NULL || top->data == '('){
                push(c[i]);
            }
            else{
                x[j] = pop();
                j++;
                push(c[i]);
            }
        }
        else if(c[i] == '('){
            push(c[i]);
        }
        else if(c[i] == ')'){
            while(top -> data != '('){
                x[j] = pop();
                j++;
            }
            pop();
        }
        else{
            x[j] = c[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s", x);
}
```

EDIT: I've taken your guy's advice and realized I was making a big mistake by not giving isOperand an argument. Also I made it so that temp is checked to be NULL before I've used a variable (I think). The code works now ONLY if i surround the entire infix expression with brackets. If I don't enclose the entire expression with brackets, it just prints back the numbers and not the operators. Any ideas why this is happening?
Edited Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *top = NULL;

void push(char x){
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = top;
    top = temp;
}

char pop(){
    struct node *temp = top;
    char op;

    if(top == NULL){
        printf("Stack Empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    op = top -> data;
    temp = top;
    top = temp -> next;
    free(temp);
    return op;
}

int precedence(char x){
    switch (x){
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool isOperand(char x){
    if(x=='^' || x=='/' || x=='+' || x=='-' || x=='*') return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main(){
    char x[100];
    char c[100];
    printf("Enter infix expression: \n");
    scanf("%s", c);
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(c[i]){

        if(isOperand(c[i])){
           if (top == NULL || (precedence(c[i])) >= (precedence(top->data)) || top -> data == '('){
                push(c[i]);
            }
            else{
                x[j] = pop();
                j++;
                push(c[i]);
            }
        }
        else if(c[i] == '('){
            push(c[i]);
        }
        else if(c[i] == ')'){
            while(top -> data != '('){
                x[j] = pop();
                j++;
            }
            pop();
        }
        else{
            x[j] = c[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;

    }

    printf("%s", x);
}
```

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger? That is the best way to debug your own code. It will allow you to step thru the code to examine its flow and variable values to find out where things start going wrong.

Comment: `if(isOperand)` Running in a debugger should show you that that is not calling the function as you intend it to be.

Comment: `if(isOperand){` --> `if(isOperand(c[i])){`

Comment: BTW: If you didn't get a warning for that it's time to turn up your compilers warning level...

Comment: `... = (precedence(top->data)) || top == NULL ...` It's not good to test for NULL **after** you've used the variable...

Comment: `printf("%s", x);` well... `x` is never terminated as a string so printing it is bad. Do: `char x[100];` --> `char x[100] = { 0 };`

Comment: `"which should be way too much for how simple it is."` There's your first problem... Underestimating the problem you're trying to solve... Maybe the 'simple' label is attached to the wrong....